# Does this make sense with the use of 'breakthrough'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> Curiosity and imagination are the **breakthrough** to having any form of discovery.

Does "breakthrough", as it is used here, make sense?

Comment: This is not a question of grammar, but of semantics and usage. You are asking whether the word "breakthrough" is appropriate in the sentence.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Sorry

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Would this sentence me correct then, in terms of syntax / word usage / vocab etc? Is there any criticism of it?

Comment: I only mean that the grammar /syntax is fine. Please Wait for others to comment or answer about the meaning and usage.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your sense, you are saying that you need curiosity and imagination to have a discovery.  Thus, **breakthrough** is not appropriate, and a word like **prerequisite** is.  Breakthrough would be better to describe the discovery itself, and not its origins or requirements.