# Use of the noun "breakthrough" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar

When someone writes

"Curiosity and imagination are the breakthrough to having any form of discovery"

Is the use of 'breakthrough' in the sentence valid because it itself, is a noun.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELU! It's really unclear to me why you are asking this question. What does "breakthrough" being a noun have to do with the validity of this sentence? Please edit your question to clarify what you think might be a problem with this sentence.

Comment: @sumelic I don't think the word break through makes sense in that context

Comment: So your question is about the meaning of the word "breakthrough"?

Comment: I think that perhaps "pathway" would be a better word to use.  Or something like "keys".

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice!  Dupe of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246859/does-this-make-sense-with-the-use-of-breakthrough

Comment: @HotLicks But look how many answers I got this time.

Comment: I agree with *Hot Licks*, and would suggest that you delete the other question.

Comment: @stevenvh I have flagged it for deletion, it does not let me delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good example for the use of the word "breakthrough", either, though not because it is a noun.
A breakthrough is momentary, whereas curiosity and imagination are continuous.

Here's an example of what's IMO a better use of the word "breakthrough:

> After having worked on the problem for weeks the team finally reached a breakthrough a few days before the final deadline.

Comment: Yes that is what i meant to say and think - thank you. Breakthrough is in momentary tense, whereas curiosity and imagination are continuous tense.